# Too many subclasses while making equipment for character (Role Playing Game)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, uml, abstract-factory

I'am building a small RPG. A character has multiple stats, like: strength, magic, archery and defense. Also a player can wear equipment, like a helmet, torso, legs, boots, gloves and a weapon. Each piece of equipment has it own stats. For example, a *silver torso* has 10 defense.

When the character has, say 15 defense, and he wears a *silver torso*, his defense will now be 25. Anyway, in order to wear equipment, it needs to be produced. At the moment I designed it with a Abstract Factory Pattern (see image).

The design has a lot of classes, with most of them are basically useless, like *Bronze Helmet*, *Silver Torso* et cetera, because they only have an instance of the class Stats.

Therefore, my question is: What is the best way to produce equipment, with less classes which are more useful. Since it is for a school project, I preferably want to make use of Design Patterns.
[image]

Comment: Whats the point of specialized classes to represent a specific type of equipment? I would expect *all* instances of e.g. boots to be represented by a single class Boots.

Comment: Why are you using factories at all? When I wear a suit, it's just ONE suit.

Comment: Why would you use a factory if you are going to call it with a specific `type` string anyway? The whole idea of the Abstract Factory is that you don't actually know the type or implementation of what you are creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The design has a lot of classes, with most of them are basically useless, like Bronze Helmet, Silver Torso et cetera, because they only have an instance of the class Stats.

You seem to be *exploding* your design for no good reason. The entire hierarchy can be replaced with just one single class called `Equipment`.

```
public class Equipment {
    private Stats stats;
    private String equiptmentName;

    //constructors and getters and setters follow..
}
```

Your `Player` class can then have a `Set` of `Equipment` as follows. You update the `Player` stats with the `stats` from `Equipment` whenever an equitpment is mounted or unmounted.

```
public class Player {
    private Set<Equipment> mountedEquipment;
    private Stats baseStats;

    public Player(Stats baseStats) {
       this.baseStats = baseStats;//set base stats for player
       mountedEquipment = new HashSet<Equipment>();
    }

    public void mountEquipment(Equipment equipment) { 
          baseStats.setMagic(baseStats.getMagic()+equipment.getStats().getMagic());

         //update base stats similarly for strength, hitpoints, etc
         mountedEquipment.add(equipment);

    }

    public void unmountEquipment(Equipment equipment) {

       baseStats.setMagic(baseStats.getMagic()-equipment.getStats().getMagic());
       //update base stats in a similar fashion for strength, hitpoints, etc
       mountedEquipment.remove(equipment);
    }

    public Set<Equipment> getMountedEquiptment() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(mountedEquiptment);
    }

}
```

You don't really need any of the *Factory* classes that you show in your question since you can add all possible `stats` to the `Equipment` and `Player` class whenever you introduce a new `Equipment` type.

Answer (score 1):

In commercial video games, many items with different attributes and possibly special effects are often implemented via the scripting system. It's hard to make it much more specific because things like script bindings and component based architecture are not strictly defined, and differ from game to game.

You can get a good idea of the innerworkings of these systems by taking a look at how (item-changing) mods for RPGs work. For example, take a look at the "Papyrus" bindings of *Skyrim*, or for a simpler example look at the lua bindings of *The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth*.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it this way:

Have an abstract class Armor that all of the Helmet, Torso, etc. inherit from. Then you can have a single Silver and Bronze class, probably also unified under a class ArmorType. I would have some kind of modifier based on which kind of equipment it is, i.e. Bronze::modifier = 1.25;, Silver::modifier = 1.5;, etc. This way, for each new ArmorType or Armor you have, you don't have to add a ton of new classes. This would only get worse as the game expands.

When actual stat calculations are done in the Armor subclasses, it will go as such:

//This is in your armor class.

```
    class Torso extends Armor {

        public Torso(ArmorType armorType) {
            this.armorType = armorType;
            this.baseStat = 10;
        }

        public double calculateStats() {
             return this.getBaseStat() * armorType.getModifier();
        }
    }
```

And now an example. If Torso has a base stat of 10 armor, Silver has a modifier of 1.5 then the resulting defense of this piece of armor would be 15. Surely you can tweak these numbers to your liking or add more facets to the calculations. This is just a simple example of the sort of thing you can do.

If you would like to keep the Stats part of your original design, I would put the Stats object in the Armor class. So you are effectively using the Decorator pattern to decorate your Armor classes with ArmorTypes. You are also just sticking a layer between your Stats class and your Subclasses of Armor.

Let me know what you think.